# Java-Keyboard input is being registered mulitple times per click

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a new Java programmer, still learning that is. I'm making a simple game for school that only needs keyboard inputs as the main function. I've run into a little problem that has been driving me crazy.

I have my KeyManager set up, and in another class I have this:

edit: I added some sort of logic to the getInput() but I still have the same problem. The edit will be above the other if statements.

```
private void getInput(){

    int OneSec =1000;
    long Time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long Time2= System.currentTimeMillis();
    long longtime = 999999;

    if(Time>OneSec){
        Time=longtime-Time2;
    }

if(Time<OneSec){

    if(handler.getKeyManager().one){
        x1++;
        System.out.println("1 has been pressed");
    }
    if(handler.getKeyManager().two){
        x2++;
        System.out.println("2 has been pressed");
    }
    if(handler.getKeyManager().three){
        x3++;
        System.out.println("3 has been pressed");
    }


}
}
```

I run the game and click 1, 2, or 3. In the console it gives me this:

1 has been pressed

1 has been pressed

1 has been pressed

1 has been pressed

ticks and frames 60

pressed

1 has been pressed

1 has been pressed

```
package dev.chris.tilegame.input;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyManager implements KeyListener {

private boolean[]keys;
public boolean up, right, down, left,one,two,three;

public KeyManager(){
    keys = new boolean[256];
}
public void tick(){
    //up=keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
    //down=keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
    //left=keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
    //right=keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
    one=keys[KeyEvent.VK_1];
    two=keys[KeyEvent.VK_2];
    three=keys[KeyEvent.VK_3];
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()]=true;
    System.out.println("pressed");

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()]=false;

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}


}
```

And this is the KeyManager class that I am using.

For some reason when I click it once, just clicking it normally, it reads it as if I clicked it multiple times, the reason being that it counts how long the button is pressed. Now I can't control how someone presses the key and this will cause problems for my game.

I just need the code to read each key press as one input, not multiple.

If I am not being clear enough or I need to post more code, please tell me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is this _KeyManager_ class ?

Comment: Can you not use a Scanner?

Comment: Can you please post your code for the `KeyManager` object, as well as where `getInput()` is called? If `getInput()` is getting called repeatedly *and* `handler.getKeyManager().one` etc. is `true` if the key is down (not just pressed), this may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: getInput() is only being called once, I can assure that.

Comment: Maybe I could use Scanner but for the purposes of the assignment I would rather use keyboard input/keylistener.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of logic to check if the key has been pressed and block further counting - until it is released. If that is the logic you are shooting for. i.e.

```
if(!pressed) { if (key pressed once) then pressed=true; }

if(key released) then pressed=false
```

Comment: That is the logic I am going for, thanks for the insight.